# PowerShell DSC Exclude property from drift test

Tags: powershell, iis, dsc, windows-server-2019, powershell-dsc

I'm using the xWebAdministration module to create IIS sites and application pools. When creating the site, a physical path needs to be specified. This path is changed with each deployment of the site resulting in DSC reporting drift. Is there a way of excluding certain properties from the drift test?

Comment: Not sure about this based on current info, i may need to confirm the details about drift test.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out PhysicalPath under the [xWebSite resource](https://github.com/dsccommunity/WebAdministrationDsc#xwebsite) is optional and doesn't need to be specified, therefore not included in the drift test. What this means is that another script can update the website path in IIS and DSC will not report drift, which is what I want.